# Integrate Youtube to Android inside Application

Tags: android, youtube-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to integrate Youtube to my android app, where I need to upload videos to users account. From the Youtube developer it seems there are two versions to do so.

1. Version 3.0(Experimental)
2. Version 2.0

So Should I use 3.0 Version for Production Apps as it is been marked Experimental?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). Even though it's classified as experimental, it's pretty stable and will be supported strongly. V2 will be deprecated and there will be only limited support. Most of developers are using V3.